# Enable two days only in date picker and disable the rest

Tags: angularjs

I am busy trying to enable 2 days only in the date picker but I am struggling to get it right. I am seeking to enable the 1st of the current month and the 1st of the next month only, everything else should be disabled.

Following is the code I am busy playing around with:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
  var DatepickerDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.dates = ["2017/08/01","2017/09/01"];

  $scope.date = new Date();

  $scope.minStartDate = 0; //fixed date
  $scope.maxStartDate = Date.parse($scope.dates[0]); //init value
  $scope.minEndDate = Date.parse($scope.dates[0]); //init value
  $scope.maxEndDate = Date.parse($scope.dates[1]); //fixed date 
  $scope.openStart = function() {

  $timeout(function() {
       $scope.startOpened = true;
     });
  };

  $scope.openEnd = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.endOpened = true;
     });
  };

 $scope.dateOptions = {
  'year-format': "'yyyy'",
  'starting-day': 1
  };
};
```

--------------------HTML------------------

```
  <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">

    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <h3>Date</h3>
        <p>
            <input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="date" is-open="endOpened" min="minEndDate" max="maxEndDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" />
            <button class="btn" ng-click="openEnd()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So basically, you want the user to be able to select only those two dates ?

Comment: @CoachNono, yes that is the goal I seek.

Comment: Is there a method in the library that can allow you to activate or deactivate dates ? The idea would be to have a method called to validate if a date can be enabled or not. What is the library you are using?

Comment: There is a method on the following : https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ on the datepicker section, there is datepicker-options which has "dateDisabled" I am attempting with it at the moment.

Comment: I think you would have to specify which dates are disabled in the `date picker-options` with the option `dateDisabled`. Let me try to write an answer.

Comment: Ohk CoachNono, much apprecite it, will grapple with it on my side as well